# Where can I find the color code in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I'm trying to plot some vectors with different colors using matplotlib, here's an example I found:
`cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('graypurple', ["#999999", "#AA00FF"])`

It looks like the color code used here is different from the code listed [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html). I'm wondering what `"#999999" and "#AA00FF"` represent? Where can I find other color codes? Are there other options of `'graypurple'`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also see [wikipedia's web colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hexadecimal code for the colour. It is RGB values encoded in 6 symbols with a little transformation. You can find tools on the internet and choose colours you'd like.

Tool1: https://htmlcolors.com/google-color-picker
Tool2: https://htmlcolorcodes.com/

Comment: Thanks! That really helps:)